# How do I slide the image on hover with CSS?

Tags: html, image, css, css-transforms

I wanna slide images from the top of images to bottom with css. Actually I write some codes. But, I dont wanna write specific pixel for sliding.

I dont want this:

```
transform:translate3d(0px,-150px,0px);
```

I want like this:

```
transform:translate3d(0px,AUTO,0px);
```

Here is my css:

```
.work
{
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:2px solid #e5e5e5;
    overflow:hidden
}

.work img
{
    width:100%;
    -moz-transition:all .6s;
    -webkit-transition:all .6s;
    transition:all .6s;
    transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)
}

.work img:hover
{
    transform:translate3d(0px,-150px,0px);
    margin:0
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="work">
   <a href="http://example.com">
      <img src="http://anlamli-guzelsozler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/krt-manzara-resimleri.jpg">
      <div>Example</div>
   </a>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...how far should the image slide up?

Comment: You can use percentage to define how far the image should slide, instead of pixels.

Comment: The image slide down as long as image height... I wanna slide down the image from top to bottom... But I dont know images height... So, there shouldnt specific pixel like -150px...

Answer (score 4):

Use percentages instead. Check this out!

It need not be specific pixels as you say- on `img:hover` if I say 100% height, it will mean the whole image height.

```css
.work {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden
}
.work img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  transition: all .6s;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
}
.work:hover img {
  transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <a href="http://example.com">
    <img src="http://anlamli-guzelsozler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/krt-manzara-resimleri.jpg">
 </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Put a `display: block;` on the `img` element and you can get rid of the whitespace below the image too!

Comment: Thanks but there is white space on the bottom of image when your mouse on the image...

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks but there is white space on the bottom of image when your mouse on the image...

Comment: didn't quite get you there. The whitespace you are refering to is becasue of the `div` containing the text 'Example'

Comment: Oh that one! That is because the you set `width: 100%` for image and the height of the image auto-adjusts.

Comment: I want to make responsive also. Is there any way?

Comment: @CrisDenolatter: looked more closely and you are right... I can't get rid of the small whitespace below the image!

Comment: @CrisDenolatter: solved it ! check the updated answer above... pls mark as correct if this helped you. Thanks!